# Cant pick picture from gallery. Result code always cancelled

Tags: android

The complete code of my `Fragment`:

```
    public class ProfileEditPictureFragment extends BaseFragment implements OnClickListener {
    private ImageView imageView = null;
    private Button buttonPick = null;
    private Button buttonSave = null;
    private Button buttonCancel = null;
    private File tempFile = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setRetainInstance(true);

        this.sessionProfilePreferences = new SessionProfilePreferences(this.getActivity());
        this.sessionLoginPreferences = new SessionLoginPreferences(this.getActivity());
        this.sessionLoginSingleton = SessionLoginSingleton.getInstance(this.getActivity());

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            this.tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp_photo.jpg");
        }
        else {
            this.tempFile = new File(this.getActivity().getFilesDir(), "temp_photo.jpg");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_picture_edit, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        this.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture_edit_imageview_photo);
        this.buttonPick = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture_edit_button_pick);
        this.buttonPick.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.buttonSave = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture_edit_button_save);
        this.buttonSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.buttonCancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture_edit_button_cancel);
        this.buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.v("ProfileEditPicture", "requestCode: " + requestCode);
        Log.v("ProfileEditPicture", "resultCode: " + resultCode);
        Log.v("ProfileEditPicture", "data: " + data);

        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == Globals.REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO) {
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = this.getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(this.tempFile);

                    Helper.copyStream(inputStream, fileOutputStream);

                    fileOutputStream.close();
                    inputStream.close();

                    this.startCropImage();
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            } else if (requestCode == Globals.REQUEST_CROP_PHOTO) {
                String path = data.getStringExtra(CropActivity.IMAGE_PATH);

                if (path == null) {
                    return;
                }

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.tempFile.getPath());

                this.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.profile_picture_edit_button_pick : {
            this.pickPicture();
        } break;
        case R.id.profile_picture_edit_button_save : {

        } break;
        case R.id.profile_picture_edit_button_cancel : {
            this.getActivity().finish();
        }
        }
    }

    private void pickPicture() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");

        this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), Globals.REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO);
    }

    private void startCropImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), CropActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(CropActivity.IMAGE_PATH, this.tempFile.getPath());
        intent.putExtra(CropActivity.SCALE, true);
        intent.putExtra(CropActivity.ASPECT_X, 3);
        intent.putExtra(CropActivity.ASPECT_Y, 2);

        this.startActivityForResult(intent, Globals.REQUEST_CROP_PHOTO);
    }
}
```

But the `resultCode` is always `0` and the data is always `null`. Permissions are set ofcourse.

**So how can i pick images from the gallery?**

I test it on Nexus 4 with Android 5.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ACTION_PICK like this

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
```

And on Activity result

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };


            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);

            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: As you are using a Fragment not an Activity you need to  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  line into your overriden method.

Comment: that does not change anything. the problem is still the same

Comment: Hope this might help https://github.com/rexstjohn/UltimateAndroidCameraGuide/blob/master/camera/src/main/java/com/ultimate/camera/fragments/SimpleAndroidImagePickerFragment.java

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem in one of my activities when I set launchMode="singleInstance" in manifest for that activity. It works fine when I remove that attribute. Although I don't know reason for this behaviour.