# Unable to select image from gallery android app (grayed out)

Tags: java, android, image, gallery

I'm trying to allow the app user to select an image from their gallery and only set the image uri if the user actually selects it. The problem I'm facing is that when I open the gallery of images all of the images are grayed out and I cannot select an image regardless of the image format. Here is my code for that section:

```
    hostImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent imageIntent = new Intent();                                                      
        imageIntent.setType("image*/");                                                         
        imageIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);                                       
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(imageIntent,"Choose host image"),000);      

        }
       }
    );
}

public void onActivityResult(int askCode, int retCode, Intent info){                             
    if (retCode==RESULT_OK){
        if (askCode==000){
            hostImageView.setImageURI(info.getData());                                      
        }     
}
```

Comment: See the answer to get the full workflow of gallery action pick. [here]


  [here]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775871/cant-pick-picture-from-gallery-result-code-always-cancelled/28776035#28776035

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your code for gallery opening as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

And use the number `2`(Or the number you are using for starting `activity`) inside `onActivityResult` method

Comment: Thanks this worked, very simple solution! Is there a way to add to that to be able to take a photo with the camera as well as choosing from the gallery or photos?

Comment: Sure. you can use `new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`

Comment: Awesome thanks. May be a stupid question but how is the simplest way of combining both choose from gallery/photos and being able to take a photo as an option to do either?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to get the selected image path instead of imagetype, and then load it into your image view. Try this,

```
    public boolean  click(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    return true;
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1 && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk symbol(*) should be given after forward slash(/).

Content-type "image/*" means category image , with any extensions (.jpeg, .png , ...)

The following worked for me

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
```